# How can I print the distance between 2 cities, given their latitude and longitude coordinates?

Tags: java, eclipse, distance, latitude-longitude

I have started my code like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

//Intro 
    System.out.print("This program calculates the distance between two cities,     given their respective latitude and longitude points.");
    System.out.println();

//Get values for Latitude and Longitude
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    double lat1 = getCoordinates(" latitude 1: ", console); // Input lat1
    double long1 = getCoordinates(" longitude 1: ", console); // Input long1
    double lat2 = getCoordinates(" latitude 2: ", console); // Input lat2
    double long2 = getCoordinates(" longitude 2: ", console); // Input long2

public static double getCoordinates(String message, Scanner scan)
    {   
    System.out.print("Please enter" + message);
    int degrees = scan.nextInt();
    int minutes = scan.nextInt();
    return Math.toRadians(degrees + (minutes / 60.0));
    }

//Calculate Distance
public static double finalAnswer(double lat1, double long1, double lat2, double long2) {
double radiusOfEarth = 6372.795; //radius of Earth in km
double distance = Math.acos(Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2) + 
                  Math.cos(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2) *
                  Math.cos(long2-long1)) * radiusOfEarth;

return distance;
System.out.print("The distance between the two cities is approximately " + distance + "km");

}
}
```

I need to be able to input the degrees and minutes (degrees, minutes) for each latitude and longitude point. However, there is a compilation error when I try to print "distance" in the last line of the code. Also, Eclipse tells me that lat1,long1, lat2, and long2 aren't being used ("Get values for Latitude and Longitude" section)? Can someone help me print the distance? Thank you.

Comment: You probably shouldn't return _before_ printing the result. and also _call_ finalAnswer.

Comment: You need to take the last curly brace, and put it before the definition of the routine "getCoordinates". This closes the definition of the routine "main". Also, the last thing main should do is to invoke your "finalAnswer" routine, pass it the *(as yet unused)* variables lat1,long1, lat2, and long2.

Answer (score 3):

In your code:

```
..
return distance;
System.out.print("The distance between the two cities is approximately " 
    + distance + "km");
..
```

change this to:

```
..
System.out.print("The distance between the two cities is approximately " 
    + distance + "km");
return distance;
..
```

Here is a [Haversine-formula implemented in Javascript](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to calculate distances. (Should be easy to translate to Java.)

[Formulas for calculating 'great circle' distances](http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#Dist):

> The great circle distance d between two points with coordinates
>   {lat1,lon1} and {lat2,lon2} is given by:
>
> d=acos(sin(lat1)*sin(lat2)+cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(lon1-lon2))
>
> A mathematically equivalent formula, which is less subject to rounding
>   error for short distances is:
>
> d=2*asin(sqrt((sin((lat1-lat2)/2))^2 + 
>                    cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*(sin((lon1-lon2)/2))^2))

Answer (score 0):

Can you please these links to find out the distance between two latitude and longitude

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12269/Distance-between-locations-using-latitude-and-long

or else 
And also another idea, You can try by using google map API  to find out the distance two cities by using latitude and longitude

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The following code can calculate the distance between to places given the longitude and latitude. it uses the haversine formula

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class haversine {
        double long1;
        double lat1;
        double long2;
        double lat2;
        haversine (Double long1, Double lat1, Double long2, Double lat2) {
                this.long1 = long1;
                this.lat1 = lat1;
                this.long2 = long2;
                this.lat2 = lat2;
        }
        double execute() {
                return Math.pow(Math.sin((lat2 - lat1)/2) ,2) + Math.cos(long1) * Math.cos(long2) * Math.pow(Math.sin((long2 - long1)/2) ,2);
        }
        double disCalc (Double exe) {
                Double radius_of_earth = 6378.1;
                return 2 * radius_of_earth * Math.asin(Math.pow(exe, 2));
        }

}
class test28 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("longitude and latitude of home : ");
                double long1 = scan.nextDouble();
                double lat1 = scan.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("longitude and latitude of travel destination : ");
                double long2 = scan.nextDouble();
                double lat2 = scan.nextDouble();
                haversine obj = new haversine(long1, lat1, long2, lat2);
                double exe = obj.execute();
                double distance = obj.disCalc(exe);
                System.out.println("The Distance is : " + distance);
                scan.close();


        }
}
```